# How to set matplotlib's shared subplots legend to be horizontal and at lower center position?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm using Matplotlib and Seaborn to plot four bar graphs with one shared legend. However, I can't make the legend to be horizontal and at the lower center. I tried to set the numbers in this line:

```
 ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.99, -0.15),
                    loc=1,
                    fontsize=13,
                    # ncol=2
                    )
```

but if the legend goes to the middle, then the distance between the two subplot columns would increase as well making it not good. [image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pdb
import pyautogui
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
from matplotlib import patches as mpatches

def convert_to_grouped_bar_chart_format(data, 
    col_1_name, col_2_name, col_3_name):
    """
        Parameters
        ----------
        data: Pandas dataframe. Format:
        
           Method               Class1  Class2     Class3
        0  Method_1           0.1       0.2        0.3
        1  Method_2           0.6       0.5        0.4
        
        Returns
        -------
        data_grouped: Pandas dataframe.
    """
    cls_list = data.columns[1:].tolist()
    col_1 = []
    col_2 = []
    col_3 = []
    (num_of_rows, num_of_cols) = data.shape
    for row_idx in range(num_of_rows):
        for cls_idx, cls in enumerate(cls_list):
            col_1.append(data.iloc[row_idx, 0])
            col_2.append(cls)
            col_3.append(data.iloc[row_idx, cls_idx+1])
            pass
        pass
    data_grouped_dict = {
        col_1_name: col_1,
        col_2_name: col_2,
        col_3_name: col_3
    }
    data_grouped = pd.DataFrame(data_grouped_dict, columns = [col_1_name, col_2_name, col_3_name])
    return data_grouped
    
def draw_four_bar_graph_seaborn():
    file_list = [
        ['Measure1_ED.csv', 'Measure1_ES.csv'],
        ['Measure2_ED.csv', 'Measure2_ES.csv']
    ]
    n_rows = len(file_list)
    n_cols = len(file_list[0])
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
   
    for idx_row in range(n_rows):
        # if idx_row > 0:
            # continue
        for idx_col in range(n_cols):
            file_name = file_list[idx_row][idx_col]
            data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
            col_1_name = 'Method'
            col_2_name = 'Class'
            col_3_name = file_name.split('_')[0]
            data_type = file_name.split('_')[1][:-4]
            
            ax = axes[idx_row, idx_col]
            # ax =axes[idx_col]
            
            data_grouped = convert_to_grouped_bar_chart_format(data,
                col_1_name, col_2_name, col_3_name)    
            splot = sns.barplot(
                # ax=axes[idx_row, idx_col],
                ax=ax,
                x=col_2_name, 
                y=col_3_name, 
                hue=col_1_name,         
                palette="magma", 
                # palette=my_pal,
                # sharey=False,
                data=data_grouped)
            splot.set_xlabel("",fontsize=1)
            splot.set_ylabel(col_3_name,fontsize=13)
            splot.tick_params(labelsize=13)            
            title_subplot = 'Title 1'            
            ax.set_title(title_subplot, fontsize=13)
            if col_3_name == 'Measure1': 
                ax.set_ylim(0, 1.10)
            else:
                ax.set_ylim(0, 2.25)
            for p1 in splot.patches:        
                splot.annotate('%.3f' % p1.get_height(), 
                           (p1.get_x() + p1.get_width() / 2., p1.get_height()), 
                           ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
                           size=13,
                           xytext = (0, 8), 
                           textcoords = 'offset points')

            if (idx_row == 1) and (idx_col == 0):
                ax.legend(
                    bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, -0.15),
                    loc=1,
                    fontsize=13,
                    # ncol=2
                    )
            else:
                splot.get_legend().remove()
            
            # Change width size
            # ax = axes[idx_row, idx_col]
            new_value = 0.35
            for patch in ax.patches :
                current_width = patch.get_width()
                diff = current_width - new_value
                # we change the bar width
                patch.set_width(new_value)
                # we recenter the bar
                patch.set_x(patch.get_x() + diff * .5)

    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)    
    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mng.window.state('zoomed') #works fine on Windows! 
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig('out.pdf')
    plt.close()

def draw_graph_then_save_and_close_automatically(func=None, args=[]):
    coords_close_graph = (1365, 12) # Auto click to close graph
    multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args).start()
    sleep(10)
    pyautogui.moveTo(coords_close_graph)
    pyautogui.click()

def main():
    draw_graph_then_save_and_close_automatically(
        func=draw_four_bar_graph_seaborn,
        args=[])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a figure-legend instead of place on on one of your axes and set the number of columns that the legend should have to the number of legend entries. Here is an example (I did find your's to be minimal enough^^)

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# create random data
y = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3))
# open a figure with two axes
fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
# plot something in the axes
axs[0].plot(y[:,0])
axs[1].plot(y[:,1:])
# define the name of the 
legendEntries = ("a","bcdefg","h")
# set figure legend entries, number of columns, location
fig.legend(legendEntries,ncol=len(legendEntries),loc="upper center")
```

[image: legends]

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py) is a doc-example, emphasizing to use the argument `ncol` to force matplotlib to expand the legend horizontally. And [here](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/01/23/matplotlib-legend-outside-of-axes/) is a tutorial/example how you can place the legend of an *axis* outside the region of the axis.

Comment: Hi, I tried it on my example because I need the legend to be at the bottom center, and I used the bbox_to_anchor argument, but unlike with my example, when I tried your code if I set the second coordinates to 0 then the legend does not show. Also, how do I set the colors of the legend to be the same as with the subplots ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The color in the legend should be automatically the same as in the subplots (as is shown in the screenshot). Placing the legend at the bottom is a quick change but a different overall behavior is odd. Can you reproduce my [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) above?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce your example but when I applied it on mine it does not work. I think it is because of seaborn.